# How to Get (Value or Comment) from a resource item in C# Resource Files into an attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, resources, resourcemanager, c#-10.0

I want to get value from resource into the DefaultValue Attribute in C#?
Is it possible and how it works if it is possible?

Example like code below

```
[DefaultValue(value:(Resources.ColorResource.Red))]
```

The resource file contains below values

[image]

The Value of "Red" key in resources is going to use like below picture

[image]

And as you can see in second image the Value keword and Comment keyword are incorrect. So how is it possible to use them like the example code?

Comment: You are out of luck.  Unless `c#-10.0` has some nifty new feature (as new releases of the compiler are apt to do), Attribute declaration parameters can only use `const` values (either literals or something declared as `const`) and a very few other things: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#2124-attribute-parameter-types

Comment: Depending on your exact use case, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods) might be an alternative.